# React Native App dependency when using real device as emulator

Tags: react-native

Iam new to React Native. Can you please let me know if there is any dependency on Android studio when creating react native app using real device as emulator?

Iam facing below issues with gradle.

Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/5.0/gradle-5.0.pom'.

Answer (score 0):

there is no extra dependency when using real device
just turn your **usb debugging** on and connect your device to pc
then

```
react-native run-android
```